# Full Calendar Multi Day event recurring with rrule

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, rrule

```
{
"id": "324sdasdaseddssds",
"title": "Test",
"start": "2022-09-01T14:00:00.000Z",
"end": "2022-09-02T15:00:00.000Z",
"isAllDay": null,
"note": null,
"rrule": {
    "freq": "WEEKLY",
    "interval": 2,
    "byweekday": [
        "su",
        "mo",
        "tu",
        "we",
        "th",
        "fr"
    ],
    "dtstart": "2022-09-01T14:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

The above provided is my sample event object,

As you can see the start and end dates suggest that It is a multi day event, but when I use the rrule, It is converting into a single day event, It is ignoring the end date, the result was the same even when I provided the duration(in hours) as suggested in the FullCalendar documentation.

[Full Calendar DOCS](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events)

My question is how do I create a proper multi day recurring event using rrule in full calendar

Comment: If the calender you are using doesn't support events over multiple days, you have to split them into multiple events covering whole days if needed.

Comment: @Christopher, I am using the FullCalendar and their recommended rrule plugin, It should be possible... on the documentation it says provide the duration for multi day event but It does not work for me

Comment: According to [the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/duration-object) the endTime can be a duration in milliseconds so: `new Date(end).valueOf()` should be accepted as a timespan over multiple days.

Comment: But it is completely ignoring the end and endTime values, It says there that if rrule is provided, calendar ignored the end time

Comment: The rrule accepts a duration value. You can set this to: `new Date(end).valueOf() - new Date(start).valueOf())`. At the [example](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-global-demo) you can see how to use the duration property on a rrule. For a visual test, you could modify it to `'25:00:00'` (25hrs) instead of the `'02:00'` (2 mins).

Answer (score 0):

`start` and `end` are ignored in fullCalendar recurring events. If you're using RRule, you can set the "until" property to control when the recurrence ends, as per the example in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin).

For example:

```
{
    id: "324sdasdaseddssds",
    title: "Test",
    rrule: {
      freq: "WEEKLY",
      interval: 2,
      byweekday: ["su", "mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr"],
      dtstart: "2022-09-01T14:00:00.000Z",
      until: "2022-09-27"
    }
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/wvjvdrJ